# Steam Browser with html5 audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, audio, browser, steam

I'm currently making a small app, which main use will be from the steam browser. However im having some issues getting audio tags to play. Though the site http://html5test.com/ suggests that it does support the audio tags.

Has anyone else had success with such things in the steam browser?

I've tried with several file formats, .wav, .mp3, .ogg

Heres the code, it works fine in IE10, FF and Chrome.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastPlayer = null;
    var loopAudio = false;

    function play_sound(file)
    {
        if (is_playing()) { return }

        lastPlayer = file;

        lastPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function() {
            if (loopAudio == true) {
                lastPlayer.play();
            }
        }, false);

        lastPlayer.play();
    };

    function stop_sound()
    {
        lastPlayer.pause();
        lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    };

    function loop_sound()
    {
        if (loopAudio === false) { loopAudio = true }
        else { loopAudio = false }
    };

    function is_playing()
    {
        if (lastPlayer === null) { return false; }
        else { return !lastPlayer.ended && 0 < lastPlayer.currentTime; }
    };
</script>
```

HTML

```
<audio id="Calm_waves" src="http://localhost/Calm_waves.mp3" preload="none"></audio>
<button class="span2 btn btn-large btn-primary" onclick="javascript:play_sound(Calm_waves);">Calm Waves</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further tinkering i managed to get this working using the ogg format, though i tried this format before, i tried again using one of the recommended converters from the WebM projects site. http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/